# Create new row for every datapoint

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, pandas

How can I create a new row for every datapoint inside a panda dataframe. For example:

```
id |2016 |2015 |2014
ID1|1|2|3
ID2|4|5|6
ID3|7|8|9
```

Convert to:

```
idnum| Date |Datapoint_Value
ID1|2014|3
ID2|2014|6
ID3|2014|9
ID1|2015|2
ID2|2015|5
ID3|2015|8
ID1|2016|1
ID2|2016|4
ID3|2016|7
```

I am importing the data from excel using pandas and would like to store inside an empty dataframe and then write to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Python_Loops\\New_doc.xlsx', 'rb'),    sheetname='Advances & Redraw') # Raw data
twisted_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `melt`.

```
twisted_df = pd.melt(raw_data, id_vars='id', 
                     var_name='Date', value_name='Datapoint_Value')

twisted_df.head()

#     id  Date  Datapoint_Value
# 0  ID1  2016                1
# 1  ID2  2016                4
# 2  ID3  2016                7
# 3  ID1  2015                2
# 4  ID2  2015                5
```

You can then export it to a CSV file.

```
twisted_df.to_csv('twisted_df.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Romain. This really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I like using indexes for this sort of thing given year really is an identifier, too. With indexes properly set, `stack` can take remaining columns names as identifiers and just have one value per row.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Python_Loops\\New_doc.xlsx', sheetname='Advances & Redraw') 

twisted_df = raw_data.set_index('id').stack().rename(columns={'level_1':'year'})

twisted_df.to_csv('twisted_df.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `id` is the index

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

Otherwise

```
df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can also transform data like this purely in Excel. If not useful for you it might be useful for others.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Select **multiple consolidated ranges** and click next
3. Leave the selection as *Create a single page field for me* and click Next
4. Select your data as the Range and click Add, then click Finish
5. A pivot table will appear that looks just like your original data. Click on the bottom right value, the *grand total*, and a new table will be created in the required format